# Change alpha of Emoji in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am populating the `title` property of the `navigationBar` with some text which might contain emojis and I'm acting on the `textColor` to fade in/out the label changing the alpha.
Basically the alpha value is driven by a `scrollView` so that the label fades along with the user scrolling.
This mechanism works perfectly for text including standard characters, but emojis are not effected by the alpha value. It seems that they are only responding to value `0.0` (and they disappear) while with any other value `> 0.0` they behave as if `alpha = 1.0`.

How can I make the whole text have the same alpha value? In particular, how can I apply an alpha value to the emoji characters contained in the string?

Here some visual example:
[image: semi transparent text]
[image: transparent text]

Note that I can not modifying the alpha of the view but the `text` alpha.

**UPDATE**

The text is assigned to the `title` property of the `navigationBar`. This case does not use the technique of placing a `UILabel` in the `titleView`

Comment: I used [this](https://gist.github.com/jeffreybergier/b0b0f7b5af3533f000b5e256f6be1077) for transparent emoji, but you should test it, because right now I'm not sure if it works

Comment: Thanks @VadimNikolaev but I think this is not working for my case: the returned values of those methods are `UIImage`s and I cannot assign a `UIImage` to the `text` property of a `UILabel`, unless I build a `NSAttributedString` containing text and image attachments (does not really sound trivial). Moreover, it not really flexible as I would also have to parse the text in order to identify if emojis are contained in the string.

Comment: Why not modify the alpha of the `UILabel`?

Comment: @Cy-4AH I just noticed that my question is a bit misleading: the text to be displayed is not assigned to a `UILabel` but to the `title` property of the `navigationBar`. I will update my question to be more precise.

Comment: I’d imagine the title in the navigation bar is a UILabel subclass. You could locate it and adjust it yourself. May not be future proof though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is scratch of code that gives effect that you want:

[image: Transparent emoji in UINavigationBar]

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
    label.text = @" Test title ";
    label.alpha = 0.2;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Asperi, I’m aware of this solution already but I have many viewcontrollers which need this fading animation and the code which handles all the transition is abstracted in another part of the code. Using the solution you proposed will require more refactoring I would like to avoid if necessary